# Using jquery form plugin for multiple forms?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a second form on my page which I want to use the jQuery Form Plugin. Is it possible? This is the code that I have so far. The first form works fine - it is called **request** and the second is called **request2** which I am having trouble implementing. This is a snippet code that is working so far - the rest can be found here http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit.

```
    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#request').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

Comment: I would recommend you reword your question, and remove all of the comments from your code that are not helping us understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just AJAXify both forms:

```
$('#request, #request2').ajaxForm(options);
```